# Как правильно инициализировать внутренние классы qt библиотек?

Tags: qt

Как вызвать  вызывать элементы которые я инициализировал в MyMainWindows ??

файл .срр

```
    #include "mymainwindows.h"
    #include <QtWidgets>


    MyMainWindows::MyMainWindows (QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    // элементы в которые заполняем
    QLabel* L_ID = new QLabel("ID:(hex)");
    QLineEdit* LE_ID = new QLineEdit();
    QLabel* L_Length = new QLabel("Length");
    QLineEdit* LE_Length = new QLineEdit();
    QLabel* L_Data_h = new QLabel("Data:(hex) ");
    // создать вектор указателей QPushButton, при создании кнопок запихивать их в вектор, а далее работать с элементами вектора.
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_0 = new QLineEdit(); // проверить через вектор
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_1 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_2 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_3 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_4 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_5 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_6 = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* LE_Data_7 = new QLineEdit();
    QLabel* L_CTime = new QLabel("Cycle Time");
    QLineEdit* LE_CTime = new QLineEdit();
    QLabel* L_ms = new QLabel("ms");
    QLabel* L_Paused = new QLabel("Paused");
    QSpacerItem * S_Paused = new QSpacerItem(0,1000, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    QCheckBox* CH_Paused = new QCheckBox();
    QPushButton* PB_start = new QPushButton();
    PB_start->setText("Старт");

    // данные которые пришли
    QLabel* L_CAN_ID = new QLabel("CAN-ID");
    QLineEdit* LE_CAN_ID = new QLineEdit();
    QLabel* L_CTime_p = new QLabel("Cycle Time");
    QLineEdit* LE_CTime_p = new QLineEdit();
    QLabel* L_Type = new QLabel("Type");
    QLineEdit* LE_Type = new QLineEdit();
    QLabel* L_Length_p = new QLabel("Type");
    QLineEdit* LE_Length_p = new QLineEdit();
    QLabel* L_Data = new QLabel("Data ");
    QLineEdit* LE_Data = new QLineEdit();
    QLabel* L_Count = new QLabel("Count");
    QLineEdit* LE_Count = new QLineEdit();



    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_ID = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_ID->addWidget(L_ID);
    phb_L_ID->addWidget(LE_ID);

    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Length = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Length->addWidget(L_Length);
    phb_L_Length->addWidget(LE_Length);

    QHBoxLayout * phb_L_Data_i = new QHBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_0);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_1);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_2);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_3);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_4);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_5);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_6);
    phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_7);

    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Data  = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Data->addWidget(L_Data_h);
    phb_L_Data->addLayout(phb_L_Data_i);

    QHBoxLayout * phb_L_CTime_1  = new QHBoxLayout();
    phb_L_CTime_1->addWidget(LE_CTime);
    phb_L_CTime_1->addWidget(L_ms);
    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_CTime  = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_CTime->addWidget(L_CTime);
    phb_L_CTime->addLayout(phb_L_CTime_1);

    QHBoxLayout * phb_L_Paused = new QHBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Paused->addSpacerItem(S_Paused);
    phb_L_Paused->addWidget(CH_Paused);
    phb_L_Paused->addWidget(L_Paused);
  // тут куспейсер итем
    QHBoxLayout * phb_Lin_Werh = new QHBoxLayout();
    phb_Lin_Werh->addLayout(phb_L_ID);
    phb_Lin_Werh->addLayout(phb_L_Length);

    //seizas
    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_CAN_ID_p = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_CAN_ID_p->addWidget(L_CAN_ID);
    phb_L_CAN_ID_p->addWidget(LE_CAN_ID);
    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Type_p = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Type_p->addWidget(L_Type);
    phb_L_Type_p->addWidget(LE_Type);
    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Length_p = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Length_p->addWidget(L_Length_p);
    phb_L_Length_p->addWidget(LE_Length_p);
    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Data_p = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Data_p->addWidget(L_Data);
    phb_L_Data_p->addWidget(LE_Data);
    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_CTime_p = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_CTime_p->addWidget(L_CTime_p);
    phb_L_CTime_p->addWidget(LE_CTime_p);
    QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Count_p = new QVBoxLayout();
    phb_L_Count_p->addWidget(L_Count);
    phb_L_Count_p->addWidget(LE_Count);

    QHBoxLayout * phb_L_answer_p = new QHBoxLayout();
    phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_CAN_ID_p);
    phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_Type_p);
    phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_Length_p);
    phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_Data_p);
    phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_CTime_p);
    phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_Count_p);

    QGridLayout* pgr_L = new QGridLayout();
    pgr_L->setMargin(5);
    pgr_L->setSpacing(15);

    pgr_L->addLayout(phb_Lin_Werh,0,0);
    pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_Data,0,1);
    pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_CTime,1,0);
    pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_Paused,1,1);
    pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_answer_p,2,0,1,2);

    setLayout(pgr_L);
 }

void MyMainWindows::on_PB_start_clicked(){
  //из LE_ID в LE_CAN_ID почему
    // не могу вызвать элементы QLineEdit LE_ID и QLineEdit LE_CAN_ID, почему  ?????
}
```

файл .h

```
#ifndef MYMAINWINDOWS_H
#define MYMAINWINDOWS_H
#include <QMainWindow>


//namespace Ui { // возможно убери эту херню
class MyMainWindow;
//}
class MyMainWindows:public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //explicit
     MyMainWindows(QWidget *parent =0);


public slots:
     void ProcessMessage(TPCANMsg msg);
     int KAN_minimal();
private slots:
     void on_PB_start_clicked();

};

#endif // MYMAINWINDOWS_H
```

Comment: Вы их создаете в конструкторе, соответственно на этом их область видимости и заканчивается. Чтобы можно было обращаться к полям класса из методов, эти поля необходимо обозначить в объявлении класса (заголовочный файл в вашем случае).

Comment: @mkkik но это как то не удобно, можно было бы в одной функции их создать а из других функций их вызывать ???

Comment: Создать можно где вам нравится, использовать тоже, объявить нужно в заголовочном файле. А вообще вы пытаетесь нагородить костылей, создайте форму в дизайнере, это будет быстрее и проще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем пришлось делать так как сказал @mkkik

файл .срр

```
MyMainWindows::MyMainWindows (QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
       // элементы в которые заполняем
       L_ID = new QLabel("ID:(hex)");
       LE_ID = new QLineEdit();
       L_Length = new QLabel("Length");
       LE_Length = new QLineEdit();
       L_Data_h = new QLabel("Data:(hex) ");
       // создать вектор указателей QPushButton, при создании кнопок запихивать их в вектор, а далее работать с элементами вектора.
       LE_Data_0 = new QLineEdit(); // проверить через вектор
       LE_Data_1 = new QLineEdit();
       LE_Data_2 = new QLineEdit();
       LE_Data_3 = new QLineEdit();
       LE_Data_4 = new QLineEdit();
       LE_Data_5 = new QLineEdit();
       LE_Data_6 = new QLineEdit();
       LE_Data_7 = new QLineEdit();
       L_CTime = new QLabel("Cycle Time");
       LE_CTime = new QLineEdit();
       L_ms = new QLabel("ms");
       L_Paused = new QLabel("Paused");
       S_Paused = new QSpacerItem(0,1000, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
       CH_Paused = new QCheckBox();
       PB_start = new QPushButton();
       PB_start->setText("Старт");
//       connect(&PB_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_PB_start_clicked()));
       connect(PB_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_PB_start_clicked()));

       // данные которые пришли
       L_CAN_ID = new QLabel("CAN-ID");
       LE_CAN_ID = new QLineEdit();
       L_CTime_p = new QLabel("Cycle Time");
       LE_CTime_p = new QLineEdit();
       L_Type = new QLabel("Type");
       LE_Type = new QLineEdit();
       L_Length_p = new QLabel("Type");
       LE_Length_p = new QLineEdit();
       L_Data = new QLabel("Data ");
       LE_Data = new QLineEdit();
       L_Count = new QLabel("Count");
       LE_Count = new QLineEdit();



       phb_L_ID = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_ID->addWidget(L_ID);
       phb_L_ID->addWidget(LE_ID);

       phb_L_Length = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_Length->addWidget(L_Length);
       phb_L_Length->addWidget(LE_Length);

       phb_L_Data_i = new QHBoxLayout();
       phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_0);
       phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_1);
       phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_2);
       phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_3);
       phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_4);
       phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_5);
       phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_6);
       phb_L_Data_i->addWidget(LE_Data_7);

       phb_L_Data  = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_Data->addWidget(L_Data_h);
       phb_L_Data->addLayout(phb_L_Data_i);

       phb_L_CTime_1  = new QHBoxLayout();
       phb_L_CTime_1->addWidget(LE_CTime);
       phb_L_CTime_1->addWidget(L_ms);
       phb_L_CTime  = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_CTime->addWidget(L_CTime);
       phb_L_CTime->addLayout(phb_L_CTime_1);


       phb_L_Paused = new QHBoxLayout();
       phb_L_Paused->addSpacerItem(S_Paused);
       phb_L_Paused->addWidget(PB_start);  // ближе к паузе
       phb_L_Paused->addWidget(CH_Paused);
       phb_L_Paused->addWidget(L_Paused);
     // тут куспейсер итем
       phb_Lin_Werh = new QHBoxLayout();
       phb_Lin_Werh->addLayout(phb_L_ID);
       phb_Lin_Werh->addLayout(phb_L_Length);

       //seizas
       phb_L_CAN_ID_p = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_CAN_ID_p->addWidget(L_CAN_ID);
       phb_L_CAN_ID_p->addWidget(LE_CAN_ID);
       phb_L_Type_p = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_Type_p->addWidget(L_Type);
       phb_L_Type_p->addWidget(LE_Type);
       phb_L_Length_p = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_Length_p->addWidget(L_Length_p);
       phb_L_Length_p->addWidget(LE_Length_p);
       phb_L_Data_p = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_Data_p->addWidget(L_Data);
       phb_L_Data_p->addWidget(LE_Data);
       phb_L_CTime_p = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_CTime_p->addWidget(L_CTime_p);
       phb_L_CTime_p->addWidget(LE_CTime_p);
       phb_L_Count_p = new QVBoxLayout();
       phb_L_Count_p->addWidget(L_Count);
       phb_L_Count_p->addWidget(LE_Count);

       phb_L_answer_p = new QHBoxLayout();
       phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_CAN_ID_p);
       phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_Type_p);
       phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_Length_p);
       phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_Data_p);
       phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_CTime_p);
       phb_L_answer_p->addLayout(phb_L_Count_p);

       pgr_L = new QGridLayout();
       pgr_L->setMargin(5);
       pgr_L->setSpacing(15);

       pgr_L->addLayout(phb_Lin_Werh,0,0);
       pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_Data,0,1);
       pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_CTime,1,0);
       pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_Paused,1,1);
       pgr_L->addLayout(phb_L_answer_p,2,0,1,2);
   //    <item row="2" column="0" colspan="2">

       setLayout(pgr_L);
 }

void MyMainWindows::on_PB_start_clicked(){
  //из LE_ID в LE_CAN_ID  
    qDebug() << "mi tyt";
    QString str = LE_ID->text();
    qDebug() << str;
    LE_CAN_ID->setText(str);
}
```

файл .h

```
#ifndef MYMAINWINDOWS_H
#define MYMAINWINDOWS_H
#include <QMainWindow>


//namespace Ui { // возможно убери эту херню
class MyMainWindow;
//}
class MyMainWindows:public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //explicit
     MyMainWindows(QWidget *parent =0);


public slots:
     void ProcessMessage(TPCANMsg msg);
     int KAN_minimal();
private slots:
     void on_PB_start_clicked();
 private:
     // элементы в которые заполняем
     QLabel* L_ID ;
     QLineEdit* LE_ID;
     QLabel* L_Length;
     QLineEdit* LE_Length;
     QLabel* L_Data_h;
     // создать вектор указателей QPushButton, при создании кнопок запихивать их в вектор, а далее работать с элементами вектора.
     QLineEdit* LE_Data_0;  // проверить через вектор
     QLineEdit* LE_Data_1;
     QLineEdit* LE_Data_2;
     QLineEdit* LE_Data_3;
     QLineEdit* LE_Data_4;
     QLineEdit* LE_Data_5;
     QLineEdit* LE_Data_6;
     QLineEdit* LE_Data_7;
     QLabel* L_CTime;
     QLineEdit* LE_CTime;
     QLabel* L_ms;
     QLabel* L_Paused;
     QSpacerItem * S_Paused;
     QCheckBox* CH_Paused ;
     QPushButton* PB_start;
     // данные которые пришли
     QLabel* L_CAN_ID;
     QLineEdit* LE_CAN_ID;
     QLabel* L_CTime_p;
     QLineEdit* LE_CTime_p;
     QLabel* L_Type;
     QLineEdit* LE_Type;
     QLabel* L_Length_p;
     QLineEdit* LE_Length_p;
     QLabel* L_Data;
     QLineEdit* LE_Data;
     QLabel* L_Count;
     QLineEdit* LE_Count;

     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_ID; 
     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Length; 
     QHBoxLayout * phb_L_Data_i; 
     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Data; 
     QHBoxLayout * phb_L_CTime_1; 
     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_CTime; 
     QHBoxLayout * phb_L_Paused; 
   // тут куспейсер итем
     QHBoxLayout * phb_Lin_Werh;
     //пришедшее сообщение
     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_CAN_ID_p;
     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Type_p; 
     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Length_p; 
     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Data_p; 
     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_CTime_p; 
     QVBoxLayout * phb_L_Count_p; 
     QHBoxLayout * phb_L_answer_p;
     QGridLayout* pgr_L; // соединитель всех лейаутов

};
```